# Parametrised and Conversion Constructors

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between parametrised constructor and conversion constructor. If so what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A parameterised constructor is (presumably) any constructor that takes one or more parameters. A conversion constructor is a constructor that can be called with a single parameter and is not declared explicit.

```
struct A {
    A();     // not parameterised or conversion
    A( int x, int y  ); // paramterised, not conversion
    A( int x );      // conversion
    explicit A( float z );    // not conversion;
};
```

Conversion constructors can be used by the compiler. Given:

```
void f( A a ) {
}
```

the compiler can call this function as:

```
f( 42 );
```

using the conversion constructor to convert 42 into an object of type A.

Comment: @avakar Thanks for the correction - don't know what happened there!